# How to estimate the order of a controlled Markov process from data?

Tags: time-series, inference, markov-process, markov-decision-process

Consider a non-stationary controlled Markov process represented by a sequence of states and actions $(s_0,a_0,\ldots,s_{T-1},a_{T-1},s_T)$ over a finite number of discrete time steps.

If the process were a first-order controlled Markov model then the transition probability between states at time $t$ would be given by
$$p_{ij}^a(t) = P(X_{t+1}=x_j\mid x_t=i,a_t=a)$$
In general, an $n$'th order controlled Markov model has transition probabilities of the form
$$p_{i_{1:n},j}^{a_{1:n}}(t) = P(X_{t+1}=x_j\mid x_t=i_1,\ldots,x_{t-n+1}=i_n,a_t=a_1,\ldots,a_{t-n+1}=a_n)$$
where the current transition depends on the last $n$ states and actions.

I have a dataset consisting of a collection of $M$ state-action trajectories $C = \{(s_0^i,a_0^i,\ldots,s_{T-1}^i,a_{T-1}^i,s_T^i)\mid i=1,\ldots,M\}$.

**Question:** How would I go about estimating the order $n$ of the Markov model representing the data?

Comment: One obvious thought would be fitting the forward stepwise multinomial model for the $n$-th state as a function of an increasing number of lagged effects. The models should be nested, therefore likelihood ratio tests could be applied to test whether the lagged effects are significant.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on what you mean by the models being nested?